# Adding to table row in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have now read this thread several times: [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery) .... and still don't understand why I can't append to a row that I just created:

```
var row = $('#sitesTable').append('<tr/>');
        row.append($('<td align="left"/>').text(k));
        row.append($('<td align="center"/>').text(v.length));
```

This simply creates an empty tr tag without appending to it:

```
<table class="sitesTable" id="sitesTable">
<tr></tr>
<th align="left">Site</th>
<th align="right">Total</th>
...
```

I appreciate any assistance, as this is starting to drive me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `var row = $('#sitesTable').append('<tr/>');` returns a reference to the table not the newly created row

you can use

```
var row = $('<tr/>').appendTo('#sitesTable');
```

```js
var row = $('<tr/>').appendTo('#sitesTable');
$('<td align="left"/>').text('col-1').appendTo(row);
$('<td align="center"/>').text('col-2').appendTo(row);
// I prefer the above format for readability
//row.append($('<td align="left"/>').text('col-1'));
//row.append($('<td align="center"/>').text('col-2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="sitesTable" id="sitesTable">
  <tr>
    <th align="left">Site</th>
    <th align="right">Total</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Also, this works:

row = $("#sitesTable").find("tr").last();

Now I can append to the newly created row. Thanks.

Comment: @SilverVesi Since you can have the added row reference, I prefer to use that